# SwiftUI OpenWeatherApi App show no content

Tags: api, swiftui

Im new to swift development and I can't make myself pass through this. I run my app and by pressing the "action" button I see no change on my text which should be the current temperature. And It's giving me an error "nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed"

My code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var temp = Int()

    func CallApi(){
                
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=budapest&appid=#########################################")
                
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let DecodedData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Api.self, from: data){
                    self.temp = DecodedData.main.temp
                        }
                    }
                }.resume()
            }

struct Api: Codable, Hashable{
    
    var main: DataStructre
}

struct DataStructre: Codable, Hashable   {
    var temp: Int
}
    
  
    var body: some View {

        Text("\(temp)")
        Button("Idojaras"){CallApi()}
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: The console message *nw_protocol_get....* has nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: It's not a good idea to post your API key in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `do/try/catch` instead of `try?`, you can get a useful error message.

```
do {
    let DecodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Api.self, from: data)
    self.temp = DecodedData.main.temp
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

In this case, I get:

> Parsed JSON number <304.31> does not fit in Int.

Changing the type of `temp` (in both the `@State` variable and the `DataStructre`) fixes the issue.

In general, I'd recommend pasting your JSON into app.quicktype.io, which will give you generated models with the correct types/structures.

---

Slightly unrelated to your issue, but you may want to look into using `dataTaskPublisher` and Combine in SwiftUI rather than `dataTask` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/processing_url_session_data_task_results_with_combine). Also, function names in Swift are generally lowercased.

Comment: Did this answer your question?